# specifing path to class file from java command line?

Tags: java

I'm running a local script to automatically compile some .java files and deploy the .class files to a remote server.

On the remote server I can then issue this command from the directory I uploaded it too (i.e., /tmp) and it works fine....

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar gpimport
```

But to execute it from my local script I need to specify the path of the .class file in /tmp so java knows where to look for it.

How do I do that? I thought it would've been really simple to figure out but I haven't had any luck so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the first classpath `.` to `/tmp`:

```
java -cp /tmp:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar gpimport
```

Comment: Huh, this post didn't turn up until after @aioobe's. hmmm

Comment: The post was deleted for a short while, but originally it was before mine ;-)

Comment: Anyway, it's a real 'duh' moment. Can't believe I didn't realize that!

Comment: @EddyR: Yepp, those are the hardest problems!